Accessing a dialog box control from a global function
Why does this expression always evaluate to 'true'? Even when the checkbox control – IDC_LANE1 – is NOT checked.
CMeetSetup MeetSetup;
if (IsDlgButtonChecked(MeetSetup.m_hWnd, IDC_LANE1) == BST_CHECKED);

CMeetSetup is a dialog window class. MeetSetup is an instance of that class (obviously). I’m trying to access IDC_LANE1 from a global function. I get no compiler errors but when I execute the program these statements always evaluate to 'true'. The code is Visual Studio 2022, MFC’s.
I expected the 2 statements would evaluate to 'false' if the control, IDC_LANE1, was not checked. Also tried (HWND)phWndView instead of MeetSetup.m_hWnd without success.
The 2 statements in question are called from a global function which in turn is called from a thread. As I understand threads they have to be global. True?

Please present us some more of your code. if (IsDlgButtonChecked(MeetSetup.m_hWnd, IDC_LANE1) == BST_CHECKED); does nothing, as it is not followed by some statement to execute, it's just terminated by the ;. How do you determine what "this expression" evaluates to? And which expression exactly? Also, IsDlgButtonChecked() returns BST_UNCHECKED if the handle or the control-id passed is invalid.

Where is CMeetSetup MeetSetup; declared? Where is the line if (IsDlgButtonChecked(MeetSetup.m_hWnd, IDC_LANE1) == BST_CHECKED);? Having this line directly after the declaration doesn't make any sense, but anyway this lane also makes no sense because it does nothing. Please show more code, so we have some context.

I see my original coding error but now I have the opposite problem - the 'if' statement always evaluates to 'false'. The code following the 'if' statement never gets executed:                                                  CMeetSetup MeetSetup;
if (IsDlgButtonChecked(MeetSetup.m_hWnd, IDC_LANE1) == BST_CHECKED)
{
m_IDC_VLANE1.SetCheck(BST_CHECKED);
for (nButton = 1; nButton <= nMaxBPL; nButton++) { dwButtonTime[1][nButton] = 999999; FormatButtonTime(1, nButton); }
m_szIDC_OTIME1.Format(_T("%02d:%02d.%02d"), 99, 99, 99);
m_IDC_L1.SetCheck(BST_CHECKED);
}

@user2325432 please don't put code (except properly formatted short oneliners) in comments, it's unreadable. [Edit] the question instead and put your code into the question.

@user2325432 please show some code fragments that make clear how you're eventually using the MeetSetup dialog (possibly MeetSetup.DoModal()?).

CMeetSetup MeetSetup;
if (IsDlgButtonChecked(MeetSetup.m_hWnd, IDC_LANE1) == BST_CHECKED)
{
  m_IDC_VLANE1.SetCheck(BST_CHECKED);
  ...
}

Because the way MFC works, this code doesn't make any sense.
When you declare the dialog with CMeetSetup MeetSetup;, the dialog windows actually does not yet exist, and any attempts to use it other than setting member variables are futile.
Especially in your case MeetSetup.m_hWnd is always NULL for the reason, the dialog window has not yet been created. It will only be created during the DoModal method. For instance using IsDlgButtonChecked on a NULL handle is pointless.
Also the dialog controls such as buttons, checkboxes etc. are only created during DoModal, therefore m_IDC_VLANE1.SetCheck(... will have no effect whatsoever.
You need to override the special method OnInitDialog and do all your initializations there. This method will be called by DoModal() right after the dialog window has been created but before it is actually displayed.

I suggest you get familiar with MFC dialogs by watching a tutorial and/or by going through a sample in a book or whatever documentation you have.
Google these terms:

mfc dialog tutorial
oninitdialog usage example


"Also all control members like m_IDC_VLANE1 will only be acatually created during DoModal" - m_IDC_VLANE1 is presumably a variable. Variables are "created" at compile-time, and initialized when constructed. Since the question claims this would be called from a "global function" the m_-prefix doesn't make sense. "You need to override the special method OnInitDialog and do all your initializations there." - Not really. The framework implements "class member <-> dialog control" mapping via the DoDataExchange method.

@IInspectable admittedy my wording is not quite accurate and I assumed the OP was eventually using DoModal.

"I assumed" - If you have to, you should make the asker provide sufficiently complete information so that you won't have to.

You're saying a dialog's variables aren't create until 'DoModal() is called? Then why does this work:                                                                                                                    CMManager MManager;
MManager.m_nMeetManager = nMeetManager;
MManager.m_nMMCom = nMMCom;
if (MManager.DoModal() == IDOK)                                                                                      The m_members are being referenced before DoModal () is called. I apologize for putting the code in 'comments' and not 'edit'.

@user2325432 well, it's poorly worded. I edited the answer.

@user2325432 no need for apologies. But you should have edited the question and put your code into the question.
